# How to use variables in ClickPatrol tracking template

Tags: php, redirect, google-ads-api, tracking, google-ads-script

I've build a own tracking template for Google ads, which looks like this:

`http://tracking.example.com?lpurl={lpurl}`

This tracking link (where {lpurl} is the final url) leads to our website and triggers the script below.

```
<?php
    header("Status: 301 Moved Permanently");
// some code to add data to our database
// then redirect traffic to url:
    header("Location:".$_GET["lpurl"]."?". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    exit;
?>
```

I have started using [ClickPatrol.com](https://www.clickpatrol.com) for click fraud protection and PPC protection. However, they also require a tracking template. They work well with Hubspot, but I don't know how to combine their tracking template with mine and modify my script.

their trackingtemplate is:
`https://example.com/?uid=[unique id]&adp={adposition}&lpm={loc_physical_ms}&lim={loc_interest_ms}&adi={adgroupid}&k={keyword}&n={network}&ci={campaignid}&d={device}&p={placement}&u={lpurl}&ma={matchtype}&ta={target}&cr={creative}`

Any idea how I can combine:

`http://example.com?url={lpurl}`

and

`https://example.com/?uid=[unique id]&adp={adposition}&lpm={loc_physical_ms}&lim={loc_interest_ms}&adi={adgroupid}&k={keyword}&n={network}&ci={campaignid}&d={device}&p={placement}&u={lpurl}&ma={matchtype}&ta={target}&cr={creative}`

I want to track my traffic with my own script and also use ClickPatrol

I attempted to merge the querystring and redirect it, but the urls in the querystring made it difficult to decode and encode, resulting in redirecting errors.